# Get the Current URL (Part of the URL only)

Tags: php, url, uri

How can i get the URL after the question mark. example

```
http://www.website.com/download.php?http://website.com/file_name/
```

and print it on my website.

Like for example :

You are downloading : `http://website.com/file_name/`

Please tell me exactly how to do it as i am very new on this kind of stuff.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hello Bryan,

Thanks for the response but i need something like automatically getting the current url on the browser which example http://www.website.com/download.php?http://website.com/file_name/ but only prints the url after the question mark. I need something like this so that i can just paste the code to the download page

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it  shows that op doesnt have minimal understanding of programming PHP so it cant reasonably answered and it doesnt have enough information and code example

Comment: it can be done by using [`explode()`](http://in2.php.net/explode) (it  Split a string by string)

    `$str = "http://www.website.com/download.php?http://website.com/file_name/ ";
    $one= (explode("?",$str));
    echo $one[1];`
     
[live example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9LrFQm)
 
(*I considered that you know how to get url)

Comment: thanks buddy.. I know you did your best to answer me. I get everything working now... thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //to get the current url

if (($tmp = strstr($url, '?')) !== false) //check if '?' is present
{
    $str = substr($tmp, 1); //to sub-string after '?'
    echo $str;
}
?>
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT! this one is perfectly WORKING on my need!

Answer (score 0):

For getting the values after the ? we can use

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

But mak sure that you only have the website link after the question mark.

Comment: im sorry but how would I apply that? I mean where to place that code?

Comment: @james how are you getting url ?

Comment: I suppose you are accessing the url http://www.website.com/download.php?http://website.com/file_name/ and if it like that you can directly use this in your message 

**you are downloading <?php $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']  ?>**

Comment: i put your code on the download.php file with the url on the browser website.com/download.php?http://website.com/fil_name but after putting your code its not showing the url.

Comment: you need to redirect to see that url in url bar ... for that you can use header function

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`:

**example:**

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

or you can store it in a variable like:

```
$a=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

or do whateve you want